# Inline AlertDialog code how to exit from calling method

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have code in an onClick event of my Activity which pops up a yes/no AlertDialog. If the user selects Yes I want to continue with the rest of the onClick method code. If they click No I want to exit the onClick method and return them to the current activity's screen.

My code is below. What's happening is that the AlertDialog pops up then closes itself automatically after a second and completes execution of the onClick method code.

How can I stop the dialog being automatically closed, and get it to behave as per the requirements above?

```
public void onClick(View view) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Warning");
        alertDialogBuilder
                .setMessage("Do you want to continue?");
        // set positive button - Carry on with the rest of the onCLick method
        alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        // set negative button: exit method and return user to activity screen
        alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                        return;
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        // show alert
        alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: Post the outer code. There's nothing of importance here.

Comment: Why not put the rest of the outer onClick into the Yes button's onClick method?

Comment: Not sure which of the outer code is relevant - the onCLick event is fired courtesy of a button in the activity layout  - android:onClick="onClick". I was trying to avoid adding the rest of the onClick code to the Yes button's onCLick method as the rest of the code is long and complex and nesting it would make it hard to read/maintain.

Comment: Any ideas why the AlertDialog is closing without waiting for user input?

Comment: Use  `dialog.dismiss();` instead of  `dialog.cancel();`

Comment: Whatever code follows in the `onClick()` method is closing the AlertDialog. If you don't want to include it in the Positive Button's `onClick()`, put it in a separate method, and call that method from the Positive Button's `onClick()`.

Comment: I've substituted dialog.dismiss(); for dialog.cancel(); and it made no difference...???

Comment: I don't understand why the following code in the onClick method is closing the AlertDialog - shouldn't the alertDialog.show() statement pause the execution flow in the onClick method?

Comment: If there are all going right then try to remove this return; and call finish()

Comment: "shouldn't the alertDialog.show() statement pause the execution flow" - Nope. That's what's causing your problem, I would imagine.

Comment: Sorry I've miunderstood how the alertDialog() works. If it doesn't interrupt execution of the method, but closes as soon as it opens. then how does the user get to respond to it?

Comment: It shouldn't close on its own. I'm assuming the code that's executing after `show()` is causing that behavior.